# How to create custom filter in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have table with rows filled up using ng-repeat. I also have an input box to search in the table. I don't want to use in build filter. I am confused with how to write a custom filter which will search in the search box and return the table rows. Also, I need search such that it match's first 4 letters if not the display whatever matches in the string. For example Search box say's "a124" then it should return all the table rows having the a124 as the first four characters if not then the default case would be search anywhere in the string.

```
<tr ng-repeat ="data in fetchedData></tr>
<th>{{data.name}}</th>
<th>{{data.id}}</th> 
<th>{{data.receivedTime}}</th>
```

Input box

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search..." ng-change="filterColumn()">
```

Controller code (I am confused what should go in )

```
$scope.filterColumn = function {
}
```

Comment: it's not really clear why a custom filter is necessary, or what you have even tried.  the process to create a custom filter is very well documented; you should consider updating your question if you have trouble after trying one of the documentation examples.  https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter

Comment: ok@Claies will update very soon !

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a custom filter for this. The normal angular filter should do fine.

Change your input to bind to search:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search..." ng-model="searchText">
```

And use that search filter to filter your ng-repeat

```
<tr ng-repeat ="data in fetchedData | filter:searchText"></tr>
```

Comment: @Priya filters should **never** modify data, they must remain idempotent.

Comment: @Claies it's a wildcard on any of the properties on search.  It could quite easily just be the search model however.  I'll update it to be clearer :)

Comment: @Priya Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service :).  If you can show your efforts to write a custom filter and why it isn't working, particularly if you capture the business logic behind it, then you'll get a much better answer.

Comment: I had just never seen that syntax used before, would be good to have what it does expressed :)

Comment: @Claies I need to write a custom filter.

Comment: @Claies fair point, although probably not necessary syntax for this answer  :).  You would use if if you wanted to search on multiple properties, whereas you could restrict your search to a single property with | filter:search.name, etc

Comment: @Priya Claies is absolutely correct.  A filter should NEVER modify the data underneath, they should only modify what is currently displayed on the DOM.  Modification should be triggered by an entirely separate event.  If you need to transform the data, you should do so in your service before the UI is painted.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this the solution which worked for me!! I got help from many AngularJS blog posts. Thanks to all of them. `

```
$scope.filter = function () {
var query = $scope.query.toLowerCase();
 $scope.details = $filter('filter')($scope.data, function(entry) {
        var concatString = '';
        angular.forEach(entry,function(key ,value){
            concatString += key + " ";
        });
         var pattern = new RegExp(query, 'i');
            return (pattern.test(concatString));
      });
    };`
```

HTML code:`<input  ng-model="query" id="filter" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-change="filter()">
<tr ng-repeat ="data in details"></tr>`

Answer (score 0):

@Priya i can see in your code, you used ng-change to call the filter method. This looks very normal way of calling a method from ancient javascript methodology.

Im suggesting you to use the way how angularjs will be using it.

For Example,

```
<input type="text" ng-model="letter">
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="friend in person.friends | startsWithLetter:letter">
    {{ friend }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here you see the ng-model="letter", this name is bind with filter called startsWithLetter. So whenever there is a change in input box then the filter will be triggered.

Here i wrote an article to [create custom filters using angularjs](http://www.poppinsboy.com/how-to-create-custom-filter-using-angularjs.html) in various types. 
This will be useful for others who read this Q&A section in future.